# how do the "jet" drivers get installed?

Tags: windows, installation, drivers, moss

We have a MOSS system. We have hosted some applications on them too. Some of the programs up there read files from the shared filesystem. In the code we user .NET providers like OleDb to be able to read these files...hence we have code like:

```
OleDbConnection cxn = new OleDbConnection();
cxn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Extended Properties='text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited';Data Source=" + file.DirectoryName;
```

What should be install to get `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0`?

Moreover, this is version 4.0. I assume this must be an old version. How to get the latest version?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which version of Windows you are running, but you can download the appropriate version from here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/239114 (these are for the Jet 4.0 version with the latest service pack).